# C++ Background problems

Tags: c++, windows

I have a c++ program that generates random files filled with gibberish, but for it to work it needs to run in the background. The method I am using generates a null window.  I have made other programs using this background method, but it doesn't work in this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>  
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
string random(int len)
 {
    string a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    string r;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) r.push_back(a.at(size_t(rand() % 62)));
    return r;
}
int main(){
    restart:
    /*This is the background code*/
    HWND window;
    AllocConsole();
    window - FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
    ShowWindow(window, 0);

    std::string file=random(1);
    std::ofstream o(file.c_str());

    o << random(999) << std::endl;
    goto restart;

    return 0;
}
```

I am using the dev C++ compiler

Comment: If you don't want a window, just build it as a GUI app and don't ever create a window.  :P  A console app is going to get a console window; GUI apps don't.

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", what actually happens and how is that different from what you expect to happen?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?  And why do you insist on using a `goto` statement? Also should you check the return value of `AllocConsole`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the same question was asked within the past couple of days, including this same bizarre line: `window - FindWindowA(...)`. It looks like the original question has been deleted, but I have to wonder what you're hoping to accomplish by re-asking it?

Comment: (Oops...Just noticed the loop.  :P  That is one of the evil `goto`s.)

Comment: Also, calling `srand(time(NULL))` in a loop is almost never a good idea.

Comment: This creates a blank command prompt session on windows, normally using the 4 lines of code here it flashes up but then disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized my problem, the goto statement needed to not include the null window rendering part, so the window wasn't re-rendered and de-rendered every time.  Also there was a - that needed to be an =.